# Casting an "alert" type in libtorrent, using Golang bindings

Tags: casting, go, bittorrent, libtorrent

I am developing a personal project in Golang, using [libtorrent-go](https://github.com/steeve/libtorrent-go)

When I do receive an alert of type `"save_resume_data_alert"`, I pick it up and have to CAST it as written in [libtorrent documentation](http://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#save_resume_data())

```
...
        save_resume_data_alert const* rd = alert_cast<save_resume_data_alert>(a);
...
```

But i really have not idea how to cast it in golang! Current code:

```
package main

import (
    lt "github.com/steeve/libtorrent-go"

    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    randomTorrent := lt.NewAdd_torrent_params()
    randomTorrent.SetUrl("PUT A MAGNET LINK HERE")
    randomTorrent.SetSave_path(".")

    ec := lt.NewError_code()
    torrentSession := lt.NewSession()
    torrentSession.Set_alert_mask(status_notification + storage_notification)
    torrentSession.Listen_on(lt.NewStd_pair_int_int(6900, 6999), ec)
    if ec.Value() != 0 {
        log.Println(ec.Message())
    }

    torrentHandle := torrentSession.Add_torrent(randomTorrent, ec)
    if ec.Value() != 0 {
        log.Println(ec.Message())
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            if torrentSession.Wait_for_alert(lt.Seconds(10)).Swigcptr() == 0 {
                log.Println("Alert timeout occurred!")
            }

            alert := torrentSession.Pop_alert()
            switch alert.What() {
            default:
                log.Printf("Alert: %#v", alert.What())
            case "metadata_received_alert":
                log.Println("Received Metadata!! finally!")
                torrentHandle.Save_resume_data()
            case "save_resume_data_alert":
                log.Println("Wrote Metadata!")
                // need to actually write the resume_data :( can't find how
            case "save_resume_data_failed_alert":
                log.Println("Failed Metadata!")
            }
        }
    }()

    select {}
}
```

Comment: seems like the question has been answered on github: https://github.com/steeve/libtorrent-go/issues/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, `libtorrent-go` developer answered me, so I am forwarding the answer for posterity reasons.

Casting C++ structures in Golang using SWIG library is documented in [SWIG-Golang documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Go.html).
In particular in this statement:

> Given a value of the interface type, Go code can retrieve the pointer
>   to the C++ type by calling the Swigcptr method. This will return a
>   value of type SwigcptrClassName, which is just a name for uintptr. A
>   Go type conversion can be used to convert this value to a different
>   C++ type, but note that this conversion will not be type checked and
>   is essentially equivalent to reinterpret_cast. This should only be
>   used for very special cases, such as where C++ would use a
>   dynamic_cast.

In that particular piece of code I posted above, the following was necessary to make it work:

```
case "save_resume_data_alert":
  log.Println("Wrote Metadata!")
  // need to actually write the resume_data :( can't find how
  SaveRDAlert := lt.SwigcptrSave_resume_data_alert(alert.Swigcptr())
  log.Printf("Resume Data: %#v", SaveRDAlert.GetResume_data())
```